# How to use outer joins via (+) in spark.sql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, outer-join

I am facing error when using `(+)` for outer joins in `spark.sql`. The below is the code I run -

```
students = pd.DataFrame(data=[['AC'],['AM'],['AD']],columns=['name'])
marks = pd.DataFrame(data=[['AC',70],['AM',95]],columns=['name','marks'])
students = spark.createDataFrame(students)
marks = spark.createDataFrame(marks)
students.show()
marks.show()

+----+
|name|
+----+
|  AC|
|  AM|
|  AD|
+----+

+----+-----+
|name|marks|
+----+-----+
|  AC|   70|
|  AM|   95|
+----+-----+

students.createOrReplaceTempView('studentsView')
marks.createOrReplaceTempView('marksView')
spark.sql('select t1.*,t2.marks from studentsView  t1, marksView t2 where t1.name = t2.name(+)').show()
```

`spark.sql('select t1.*,t2.marks from studentsView  t1, marksView t2 where t1.name = t2.name(+)').show()` gives the error

```
    ParseException: 
mismatched input ')' expecting {'(', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANTI', 'ANY', 'ARCHIVE', 'ARRAY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AT', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'BETWEEN', 'BOTH', 'BUCKET', 'BUCKETS', 'BY', 'CACHE', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CHANGE', 'CHECK', 'CLEAR', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTERED', 'CODEGEN', 'COLLATE', 'COLLECTION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMPACT', 'COMPACTIONS', 'COMPUTE', 'CONCATENATE', 'CONSTRAINT', 'COST', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_USER', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', DATABASES, 'DBPROPERTIES', 'DEFINED', 'DELETE', 'DELIMITED', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DIRECTORIES', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'DIV', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'END', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EXCEPT', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTERNAL', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILTER', 'FILEFORMAT', 'FIRST', 'FOLLOWING', 'FOR', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FORMATTED', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FUNCTION', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GROUP', 'GROUPING', 'HAVING', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INNER', 'INPATH', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'INSERT', 'INTERSECT', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'IS', 'ITEMS', 'JOIN', 'KEYS', 'LAST', 'LATERAL', 'LAZY', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCATION', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGICAL', 'MACRO', 'MAP', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'NAMESPACE', 'NAMESPACES', 'NATURAL', 'NO', NOT, 'NULL', 'NULLS', 'OF', 'ON', 'ONLY', 'OPTION', 'O...

== SQL ==
select t1.*,t2.marks from studentsView  t1, marksView t2 where t1.name = t2.name(+)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Is there a string formatting issue in providing the sql query with `(+)`?

Comment: I don't think you can use + operator this way in spark sql. + is supported in oracle this way for joins. In spark sql it would work without providing that additional + in the query.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya does it mean that for outer joins in spark.sql I will have to switch OUTER JOIN ON form of syntax? Could you please share some source of this confirmation that (+) operator will not work in spark.sql? Lest there is some way to bypass this.

Comment: And the manual & your other searching says what about spark outer joins?

Comment: @AnirbanChakraborty you can check out this link. Its related to SQL but the same applies to SQL because spark.sql relates to sql in most of the cases apart from some edge cases. http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/outer_joins

Comment: Why use the dated (+) notation? Wasn't that ANSI SQL-89?  The ANSI-92 standards use `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL OUTER`..   IF you can use the 92 standards, then I believe your SQL would become `SELECT t1.*,t2.marks FROM studentsView  t1 LEFT JOIN  marksView t2 ON t1.name = t2.name`